# Do I need a downrod or special bracket for a ceiling fan mount on a slanted ceiling?

Tags: ceiling-fan

Other than aesthetics, is there any reason not to mount a ceiling fan tight against a gently sloped ceiling? (i.e. my fan does not have a ball+socket joint).

Would this significantly impact air circulation, make it wobble, stress the mount, etc.?

Comment: Most ceiling fan mounts are made to "hang" from a ball and socket type arrangement.  So, for most fans that I've seen, this wouldn't be possible.  That said, it probably is possible for some fans.

Comment: FYI, "flush" is not synonymous with "tight to". The word means more like "aligned with on the surface". A nail driven flush feels like part of the material it was driven into, for example.

Comment: What do the instructions say about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some fans are designed to be installed without a down rod, where the fan housing mounts rigidly to the base plate (which in turn mounts to the electrical box). These are more rare lately since the stubby downrod approach tends to be simpler to install (and probably cheaper to manufacture).

Whether those fans' housings are robust enough to handle their weight at an angle will depend on the particular fan. I would expect that the fan's instructions would specify whether this is an option for low-profile mounting. It's not going to be a matter of special brackets, but housing design.

Comment: Have you ever seen a fan advertised as being suitable for mounting at an angle though? I never have.

Comment: Can't say that I have, but I don't recall looking for it either.

Answer (score 1):

For 40 years we have had a heavy Hunter oil bath fan installed on a 3-in-12 pitch ceiling. I got a longer rod than what came with the fan (12" I think).  With a hacksaw, I cut off the shroud on an angle. The fan works with that much extra length. I would not try to mount a fan on a sloped ceiling with the short pipe that comes with the fans.

[**EDIT**
In our installation the down slope fan blade is 12" below the ceiling and the upslope blade is 24" below the ceiling.

I now wonder whether the first rate way to hang a fan from a sloped ceiling would be by installing a wedge to have the shroud level. A simpler possibility would be to mount the shroud further down the rod, if the design allows that.

A more steeply sloped ceiling might require an 18" or even a 24" down rod.